# CMake Boost 1.59.0 geometry

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am fairly new to using boost along with C++. I have just installed Boost 1.59.0 and I want to use the geometry library.

If I include `FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.47 REQUIRED )` it finds boost and no problems arises. If I then include `FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.47 COMPONENTS geometry REQUIRED )` I get the following error:

```
 Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.59.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_geometry

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

If I run the following `[ -f /usr/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp ] && echo "Found" || echo "Not found"` in the CLI I get `Found` as a result. So it seems that it's there, but CMake tells me it's not.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Difficulties-with-component-search-by-FindBoost-tp7585638p7585639.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COMPONENTS` is required only for built libraries. Geometry is an header-only library so it's not needed. You need only to find the boost headers location.