# CMake cannot find Boost libarary

Tags: boost, cmake

I'm new to Cmake. I read posts of the same problem but I still cannot solve my problem. Sorry about the same question.

My boost include is in: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include
My boost lib is in: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
SET(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0)
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include)
SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS optional REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDEDIR})
target_link_libraries(hash ${Boost_LIBRARYDIR})
```

The debug message I got is:

```
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:551 ]     _boost_TEST_VERSIONS =   1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:553 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:555 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = ON
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:557 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = 
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:559 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = 
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:561 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = 
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:613 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables:
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:615 ]   BOOST_ROOT = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:617 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:619 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:621 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:690 ] Include debugging info:
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:692 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:694 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost/boost-1_46_1;boost/boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost/boost-1_46_0;boost/boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost/boost-1_46;boost/boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost/boost-1_45_0;boost/boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost/boost-1_45;boost/boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost/boost-1_44_0;boost/boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost/boost-1_44;boost/boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost/boost-1_43_0;boost/boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost/boost-1_43;boost/boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost/boost-1_42_0;boost/boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost/boost-1_42;boost/boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost/boost-1_41_0;boost/boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost/boost-1_41;boost/boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost/boost-1_40_0;boost/boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost/boost-1_40;boost/boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost/boost-1_39_0;boost/boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost/boost-1_39;boost/boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost/boost-1_38_0;boost/boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost/boost-1_38;boost/boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost/boost-1_37_0;boost/boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost/boost-1_37;boost/boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost/boost-1_36_1;boost/boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost/boost-1_36_0;boost/boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost/boost-1_36;boost/boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost/boost-1_35_1;boost/boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost/boost-1_35_0;boost/boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost/boost-1_35;boost/boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost/boost-1_34_1;boost/boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost/boost-1_34_0;boost/boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost/boost-1_34;boost/boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost/boost-1_33_1;boost/boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost/boost-1_33_0;boost/boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:714 ] location of version.hpp: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/boost/version.hpp
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:738 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.58.0
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:824 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = 
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:834 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:877 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = -
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:879 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -d
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:933 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/stage/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/../lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG   = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/stage/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/../lib;/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1045 ] Searching for OPTIONAL_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_optional-mt-1_58;boost_optional-mt;boost_optional-mt-1_58;boost_optional-mt;boost_optional
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1087 ] Searching for OPTIONAL_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_optional-mt-d-1_58;boost_optional-mt-d;boost_optional-mt-d-1_58;boost_optional-mt-d;boost_optional-mt;boost_optional
-- [ /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1153 ] Boost_FOUND = 1
CMake Error at   /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.4.1/share/cmake/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1247 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Boost version: 1.58.0

Boost include path: /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include

Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

      boost_optional

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_link_libraries):
Cannot specify link libraries for target "hash" which is not built by this
project.

CMake does not support this but it used to work accidentally and is being
allowed for compatibility.

Policy CMP0016 is not set: target_link_libraries() reports error if its
only argument is not a target.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0016" for
policy details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and
suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I execute by running cmake .

Edit. The problem has been solved. The correct CMakeLists.txt should be :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
SET(BOOST_ROOT /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0)
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)

include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})
add_executable(myProgram main.cc)
```

The error occurred because Boost.Optional is a header-only file and I do not need to locate the lib for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.Optional is a head only libraries:

see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

The `COMPONENTS` in find_package is required only for built libraries.  So, you only need to write:

```
find_package(Boost 1.58.0 REQUIRED)
```

see similar link: [CMake Boost 1.59.0 geometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843400/cmake-boost-1-59-0-geometry)

Comment: I modified find_package and delete the line with "target_link_libraries". I also added  "add_executable(myProgram main.cc)" at the end of the file. It shows no error but I still cannot find my executable.

Comment: run `make` after you execute `cmake ..`

Comment: After I execute make it still tells me 'boost/optional.hpp' file not found. :(

Comment: can you print the variable `${Boost_INCLUDEDIR}`? Use: `message(STATUS "include dir: ${Boost_INCLUDEDIR}")`

Comment: It is empty. It only prints "include dir: ". But when I turn on debug (i.e. -DBoost_DEBUG=ON") it shows "BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0/include". Why it is like this?

Comment: It is working now. I changed "include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDEDIR})" to "include_directories(${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})". Thank you so much! Spent whole night setting it up.

Comment: use `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}` or `${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR}`  not  `${Boost_INCLUDEDIR}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, Boost.Optional is a header-only library so it's not possible to locate its shared lib which name, according to docs, should be specified in the `components` argument. I guess it's the root of the problem, and you should simply search for boost itself without any component:

```
find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
```

In this case there's no additional precompiled library so `target_link_libraries` for *Boost.Optional* is not needed (but may be required for other 3rd-party libs in the project.

Comment: So I change "find_package(Boost COMPONENTS optional REQUIRED)" to "find_package(Boost)"? Do I need to modify target_link_libraries?

Comment: It does not give me error message now, but I cannot find the executable after I use "cmake ." I change the find_package as you suggested and delete target_link_libraries line. I also added "add_executable(myProgram main.cc)" at the end of the line.