# How can I tell cmake to find boost after installing it via apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, boost, apt-get

I installed boost like proposed in this [Installing Boost under Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu) question. However, when I try to execute a cmake file which tries to include boost like:

```
find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
```

It tells me that it can't find neither of the following two files:

BoostConfig.cmake
boost-config.cmake

There is the hint that one should add the installation prefix of "Boost" to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or set "`Boost_DIR`" to a directory containg on of the above files.

However, how can I do this? And how do I know where to find these files or the directory after installing it via `apt-get`?

I am using cmake version 3.5.1, for boost I found out the version via

```
dpkg -s libboost-all-dev
```

which is `1.58.0.1ubuntu1`

Comment: Which version of boost and which version of CMake?

Comment: cmake 3.5.1, boost I could not tell due to installing it via apt-get

Comment: Sure you can, those packages also have version numbers. If the boost is newer than 1.61, [this version of cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.5.1/Modules/FindBoost.cmake#L830) won't find it. Or just look inside `boost/version.hpp`.

Comment: boost is 1.58.0.1ubuntu1 , i edited the question

Comment: Interesting. Those two should work together. Unfortunately it's been a while since I've developed on a linux box... hopefully someone else can point out the issue.

Comment: I guess in the worst case forget about finding it and just add include directory for [`/usr/include`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost1.58-dev/filelist) and [`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libboost-system1.58-dev/filelist) (assuming you're on 64bit) -- that's where the files ought to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rm` the `CONFIG` from your find_package cmd.

i.e: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)`

The `CONFIG` is head-only, see this link: [CMake cannot find Boost libarary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669060/cmake-cannot-find-boost-libarary/34669399#34669399)